# A, B, C construct an equilateral triangle.Check if the statements are true or not.

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

Let A, B, C construct an equilateral triangle. I want to check if the following statements are true or not.

1. $\vec{AB}+\vec{AC}=\vec{BC}$

   I think this is wrong because: $\vec{AB}=\vec{AC}+\vec{CB}=\vec{AC}-\vec{BC}\Rightarrow -\vec{AB}+\vec{AC}=\vec{BC}$.
2. $2\vec{AB}+\vec{AC}=\vec{AC}+\vec{BC}$

   That would mean that $2\vec{AB}=\vec{BC}$, or not? I think that this is wrong since I don't see how this could be true. So, I think that this statement is wrong.
3. $\vec{AB}\cdot \vec{BC}=\vec{AC}\cdot \vec{CB}$

   This is correct since the dot product is equal to the product of the length of the two vectors and the angle, which is the same at both sides of equality.
4. $|\vec{AB}+\vec{AC}|=2|\vec{BC}|$

   Could you give me a hint for this one?
5. $\vec{AB}-\vec{AC}=\vec{BC}$

   This is wrong, since it should be $\vec{AB}-\vec{AC}=-\vec{BA}-\vec{AC}=-(\vec{BA}+\vec{AC})=-\vec{BC}=\vec{CB}$.

$$$$
Are my thoughts correct?

Comment: Your thoughts in $1,2,3, and 5$ are right. But $4$ is wrong, and to see that you can draw the triangle and the sum of the 2 vectors is the vector joining $A$ and  $4th$ vertex of the parm. It is strictly less than $2BC$

Comment: At 4 can we also use the triangle inequality as follows? $$|\vec{AB}+\vec{AC}|\leq |\vec{AB}|+|\vec{AC}|=|\vec{BC}|+|\vec{BC}|=2|\vec{BC}|$$ @FareedAF

Comment: One should also point out the existance of the trivial solution A=B=C where all are true.

Comment: Ah ok! Is my previous comment about using the triangle inequality correct? If yes, how can we check if we have strictly less and not equality? @PaulChilds

Comment: Yes, this is a situation for using the triangle inequality.

Comment: But how can we check if we can get the equality or jst the strict less symbol? @PaulChilds

Comment: Also how could we justify 2? @FareedAF

Comment: 2 implies that $2\vec{AB}=\vec{BC}$ (since the addition of vectors is commutative) and since $\vec{AB}$ and $\vec{BC}$ does not have the same direction (the 2 vectors intersect at $B$), then the equality doesn't hold. Therefore, the statement is false.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In part 4, $|\vec{AB}+\vec{AC}|=a\sqrt{3}$ were $a$ is the length of the side of the equileteral triangle (You can check that by applying Pythagoras theorem in the semiequiletral triangle that is formed by drawing a height (median) in the triangle $ABC$)

So you'll get that $|\vec{AB}+\vec{AC}|=a\sqrt{3}$
And $2|\vec{BC}|=2a$

So as a result we get that $|\vec{AB}+\vec{AC}| \lt 2|\vec{BC}|$

Except for $a=0$

And the other 4 ideas are correct.

Comment: We cannot get the result by the triangle inequality $$|\vec{AB}+\vec{AC}|\leq |\vec{AB}|+|\vec{AC}|=|\vec{BC}|+|\vec{BC}|=2|\vec{BC}|$$ can we?

Comment: You can't get the above results using the triangle inequality, but what you wrote is right.

Comment: Ok! Thank you very much!! :-)

Comment: @Mary Star your much welcome ...